# How to test Twilio calling my REST API via POST when a user sends an sms to a short code?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, twilio

I am new to WebApi and MVC4 and am trying to create a Rest API in C#. 
I am using twilios tools TwilioCSharp and Twilio.MVC. 
How do I test the interface between the User sending a text to the short code of Twilio and Twilio doing a HTTP Post to my URL and my api sending the response back via an sms? I am behind a firewall and I don't have any clue how to test if my api actually works. 
Please help.

Also if anybody can post some examples of how to validate to check if the POST request coming is from Twilio would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

In order to test your code, I'd suggest installing a request forwarding utility.  I've found that the one from [ForwardHQ](https://forwardhq.com/) works well.

Basically request forwarding utilities like ForwardHQ do two things for you:

1. It creates a publicly accessible URL for you, that you can tell Twilio about.
2. It creates an SSH tunnel between a port on your machine and a server on the internet

When Twilio needs to make an HTTP request because it received an inbound SMS or voice call, it will request the ForwardHQ URL.  Forward knows how to take that request and send it to the port running on your local machine.  That port map to your local web development server running in order to process the request and return the result to Twilio.

The [install instructions](https://forwardhq.com/support/installation) for Forward are pretty straight forward.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will try and let you know. Thank you.